# Show count in SSRS using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Below is my sql query

```
USE AdventureWorks2012

Select EDH.*, 
case when EDH.DepartmentID between 1 and 5 then 'DEPT-A'
when EDH.DepartmentID between 5 and 9 then 'DEPT-B'
when EDH.DepartmentID between 9 and 30 then 'DEPT-C' end as [DEPT TYPE]---, count(EDH.DepartmentID)
 from HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory EDH
left outer join HumanResources.Employee EM on EM.BusinessEntityID =  EDH.BusinessEntityID
group by EDH.DepartmentID, EDH.BusinessEntityID, EDH.ShiftID, EDH.StartDate, EDH.EndDate, EDH.ModifiedDate
```

I'm bringing the Dept Type column either as Dept-A, B or C based on Case when Condition on Department ID.

Now in the SSRS report I want to show the count of the Department Column in the footer such as

**Dept Count[A/B/C]:  49/195/46**

How to show the count in the report? Should I modify the query or there is some change required in the report

Comment: You can use inbuilt **count function** in SSRS. How are you grouping the report. Can you show what is your desired output is?

Comment: @AnupAgrawal: Please give an example the count function. The desired output is included in question (in Bold Letters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an expression like:

```
="Dept Count [A/B/C]: "
  & Sum(IIf(Fields!DeptType.Value = "DEPT-A", 1, 0)) & "/"
  & Sum(IIf(Fields!DeptType.Value = "DEPT-B", 1, 0)) & "/"
  & Sum(IIf(Fields!DeptType.Value = "DEPT-C", 1, 0))
```

This will work as you have a set amount of department types. Use a conditional `Sum` with `IIf` to get the numbers in each account.

Works on some simplified data:

[image]

Comment: For some reasons the count is coming incorrect. I have mentioned the count in the question itself

Comment: Sorry the count is right.. I verified from database. but somehow when i export the report data into excel, 6 rows are missing..quite weird..